# C# - Appending strings to a string array

Tags: c#, arrays

How can I append strings to an array if a certain checkbox is true?

```
//Create an array to hold the values.
string[] charArray;

if (abc.Checked == true)
{
    //append lowercase abc
}

if (a_b_c.Checked == true)
{
    //append uppercase abc
}

if (numbers.Checked == true)
{
    //append numbers
}

if (symbols.Checked == true)
{
    //append symbols
}
```

Comment: Every time you write `== true`, God kills a puppy.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know god cared about my bad programming practices.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You typically don't want to try appending to an array in .NET.  It can be done, but it's expensive.  In this case, you want to use a [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx)

Example:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

if (abc.Checked)
{
    //append lowercase abc
    sb.Append(textbox1.Text.ToLower());
}
```

When you're done, you can get the string by calling `sb.ToString()`, or get the characters by calling `sb.CopyTo()`.

Naming an array of strings "charArray" is very confusing.

Or are you trying to append *strings*, not append characters to a string?  You want to use a `List<string>` for that, rather than a `string[]`.

Example:

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>();

if (abc.Checked)
{
    // append lowercase abc
    strings.Add(textbox1.Text.ToLower());
}
```

Comment: `sb.Append(textbox1.Text.ToLower());
` What if I wanted to append multiple values. Like the whole alphabet?

Comment: jeez chill with the ==true hating. I leave it because I like it for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

why don't you append strings to List, and then convert it to array?

Comment: var list = new List<string>(); list.Add("any string"); var a = list.ToArray();

Answer (score 3):

An array by definition has a fixed size. If telling your strings apart is important for you, and/or you want to be able to iterate over them, sort them,  etc. - use a [StringCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.stringcollection.aspx) or another better suited [collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ytkdh4s(v=VS.80).aspx). If you just want to append a string to another string, use [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx), as Jim said.